# Pitfalls of Windows XP Virtual Machines

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

What problems have you faced when registering and activating Windows XP under VirtualBox or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard XP activation rules apply (Ars Technica had an article on [XP activation rules](http://arstechnica.com/wankerdesk/01q1/wpa-1.html) back-in-the-day). The best thing to do is to set up your virtual machine as required (RAM, main HDD) before activation, then create a snapshot of it; for any subsequent changes (eg, extra disks), revert to that snapshot.

If VirtualBox supports any differencing mechanisms, utilise those, too.

Answer (score 1):

No full DirectX support.

Comment: I thought the latest versions of VirtualBox (and VMware) supported hardware acceleration now?

Comment: Not DX10 and its still loosely emulated, no full support.

Comment: Before your comment it had never occurred to me the idea of even wanting DX10 on a VM... And given that I don't use it even on *real hardware* ... well, let's say that isn't a concern, **for me** .

Comment: Ah - I'd not thought of DX10. But, like voyager, I've no reason to  :}

Comment: DX10 is Vista-only anyway, so a moot point for **XP** in a VM ...

Answer (score 0):

[No firewire support](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=9637&start=0).