# Hardware changes to require XP Activation ? (for a Virtual Machine)

Tags: windows-xp, virtualization, windows-activation

I have WXP-64 running on a VM and, for testing and performance reasons, I would like to occasionally change the allocations for it.  Changes might include:

- Number of CPU cores,
- Amount of RAM
- Add/remove network adapters.

But I'm concerned that XP will demand re-activation and that I might eventually have licensing issues if I do this.

So, can anyone tell me:

1. What kind of changes trigger re-activation in XP?
2. Is there limits or caveat with regard to re-activation?

I've perused [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/4262/pitfalls-of-windows-xp-virtual-machines) and [the article](http://arstechnica.com/wankerdesk/01q1/wpa-1.html) it references, but wanted more recent and verified info.

(*FWIW, I'm not trying to cheat: the OS copy was purchased explicitly for the VM.*)

Answer (score 0):

Windows will trigger the o'l hardware change re-validation when there is an extensive harware change; updating your video card or changing a NIC won't do it but if you remove the drive and connect it to a sepperate machine it will request revalidation.

Microsoft allows the origional purchaser/ license owner to use 'said' license as you see fit and have details about their licenses on their site.

Generally the verification can be done in a few minutes through the prompt online or even on the phone so I would not worry about this step (it is annoying but unless you dig deep into Windows there is no way around it)